# Swiper + Ionic TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js

This error appears if I add more than one swiper-containers to my Ionic App in two different pages.

```
$rootScope.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   direction: 'horizontal',
   loop: true,
   effect: 'fade',
   autoplay: 4000
});
```

Comment: Note that using Framework7, a swipeable tablist contains a swiper-container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to solve this was to place an id at each swiper-container div and find the element with the id of each div, not the class .swiper-container.
This way the two elements do not get confused.

```
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function () {
      console.log("Loading Swiper");
      $rootScope.swiper = new Swiper(angular.element(document.querySelector("#homeSwiper")), {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: true,
        effect: 'fade',
        autoplay: 4000
      });

    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function () {
      console.log("Destory");
      $rootScope.swiper.destroy();
    });
```